# Fullcalendar Showing multiple same date in Day views

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm facing a real trouble with the fullcalendar plugin, it is showing  same date multiple time. see. in image date 9th of march.
I found the reason when I change my system timezone which have negative offset.
but I don't know how to handle this.

[image]

Comment: Please provide basic code.

Comment: please check the code at https://jsfiddle.net/awadeshK/bvnmf8ko/

Comment: fiddel not working. jq undefined

Comment: Chintan Mirani, I've just post the code snippet. I cannot post the whole code

Comment: Where are your events? In which function are you rendering events? You should render events in event or eventSources configuration in json format.

Comment: I've json objects and I'm creating a selectlist in dayRender event. Can you suggest me how can I apply my own timezone such as 'Jordan Standard Time or India Standard Time" in fullcalander and remove the dependency of client computer system time zone?